# To Validate angular form and Json(Basic validaton already implemented)

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-material2

When we hover over the first column of the table a tooltip appears and then on clikcing on the button presnt in the tooltip mat dialog opens up.

The dialog contains 2 sections left and Edit json and. In the left which row is selected its corresponding data on the right side as json is shown.

1) Basic form validation works but I need to show some message(if the form is not valid) incase user edits the json and tries to click on the button.
(tried using blur [ngModelOption] [ngFormOption] onUpdate property but was not able to achieve)

For json part as well basic validation works but for below points how validation can be provided:

1) It doesn't validate if I make a key as empty string.

2) How can I make a particular key mandatory.

Stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-qxxgcp?file=app%2Falert-dialog%2Falert-dialog.component.html

Excerpt from alert-dialog.component.ts

```
<form #jsonform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddNewAlert()">
            <json-input [(ngModel)]="data.data[incomingSelectedAlert].conditionals" name="result"></json-input>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success alertButtonSubmit" [disabled]="jsonform.invalid">Add As New Alert</button>
</form>
```

json-input.component *(I have NG_VALIDATORS and valdidate function performing basic json validation)*

```
@Component({
selector: 'json-input',
template:
    `
    <style>
     textarea {
     height: 421px;
     width: 480px;
     resize: none;
    }
    </style>
    <textarea
      [value]="jsonString" 
      (change)="onChange($event)" 
      (keyup)="onChange($event)">
    </textarea>
    `,
providers: [
{
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => JsonInputComponent),
  multi: true,
},
{
  provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => JsonInputComponent),
  multi: true,
}]       
})
export class JsonInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
private jsonString: string;
private parseError: boolean;
private data: any;

// this is the initial value set to the component
public writeValue(obj: any) {
    if (obj) {
        this.data = obj;
        // this will format it with 4 character spacing
        this.jsonString = JSON.stringify(this.data, undefined, 4); 
    }
}

// registers 'fn' that will be fired wheb changes are made
// this is how we emit the changes back to the form
public registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
}

// validates the form, returns null when valid else the validation object
// in this case we're checking if the json parsing has passed or failed from the onChange method
public validate(c: FormControl) {
    return (!this.parseError) ? null : {
        jsonParseError: {
            valid: false,
        },
    };
}

// not used, used for touch input
public registerOnTouched() { }

// change events from the textarea
private onChange(event) {

    // get value from text area
    let newValue = event.target.value;

    try {
        // parse it to json
        this.data = JSON.parse(newValue);
        this.parseError = false;
    } catch (ex) {
        // set parse error if it fails
        this.parseError = true;
    }

    // update the form
    this.propagateChange(this.data);
}

// the method set in registerOnChange to emit changes back to the form
private propagateChange = (_: any) => { };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done what you need with the following steps:

- Convert the json form to reactive forms instead of template forms (it's not a good practice to use template forms and retrieve the `NgForm` directive in TypeScript code)
- Add `forbiddenFields` (contains empty string since it's an actual valid key in JS) and `mandatoryFields` to the `JsonInputComponent`

  ```
  mandatoryFields: string[] = ["conditionals", "offset", "alert"];
  forbiddenFields: string[] = [""];
  ```
- Implement the fields check in the `onChange` function:

  ```
  private onChange(event) {
      // get value from text area
      let newValue = event.target.value;

      try {
          // parse it to json

          this.data = JSON.parse(newValue);
          const datakeys = Object.keys(this.data);

          const containsForbiddenFields = datakeys.some(x => this.forbiddenFields.indexOf(x) >= 0);
          const containsMandatoryFields = this.mandatoryFields.every(x => datakeys.indexOf(x) >= 0);
          this.parseError = containsForbiddenFields || !containsMandatoryFields;
      } catch (ex) {
          // set parse error if it fails
          this.parseError = true;
      }

      // update the form
      this.propagateChange(this.data);
  }
  ```

For the full working solution, here is the forked [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-x1gtcp?file=app%2Fjson-input.component.ts)

Comment: seems to be working , will implement and update, please suggest how can I also pass the whole json thing after getting edited once validation is success on click of the Add As New button or show a message if json validation does not pass , thanks

Comment: I've added a `onAddNewAlert` scaffold in the Stackblitz. In short, you have to implement some logic based on `this.jsonform.valid`, the value of the json field is in `this.jsonform.value`

Comment: All of this works in the stackblitz though. Shouldn't it be a new question?

Comment: ok I'll create a new post but also in my given stackblitz link in the question the row gets highlighted when the dialog opens up

Comment: I have created a new post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60811034/to-highlight-the-selected-row-in-mat-selection-list-and-show-its-corresponding-d , I'll add the bounty(in 8hrs) now its not allowing

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out when I have some spare time during off hours

Comment: the default selection doesn't work , please suggest , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60811034/to-highlight-the-selected-row-in-mat-selection-list-and-show-its-corresponding-d

Answer (score 1):

I have followed following steps and updated your code with the requirements and it seems to be working fine:

> For adding validations to check empty string and mandatory keys in
>   nested objects,   I have added logic on ngOnInit() method when value
>   of form changes in AlertDialogComponent with the help of control value
>   accessor.

Added these variables to validate form and getting keys of JSON Object,

```
isFormValid = true;
mandatoryField = ['conditionals', 'offset', 'alert', 'mTitle'];
allMandatoryFieldsExists: boolean;
```

Attaching my solution and main code here,[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-a9hcp1?embed=1&file=app/alert-dialog/alert-dialog.component.ts&view=preview)

```
this.jsonform.statusChanges.subscribe(() => {
        let data = this.jsonform.value.result;
        let keys = [];
        if(data) {            
          for(var i in data) {
            keys.push(i);
            if(i === 'offset' && data[i] === '') {
              this.isFormValid = false;
              return;
            } else {
              this.isFormValid = true;
            }

            if(i === 'conditionals') {
              for(var j in data[i][0]) {
                keys.push(j);
                if(data[i][0][j] === '') {
                  this.isFormValid = false;
                  return;
                } else {
                  this.isFormValid = true;
                }
              }
            }

            if(i === 'alert') {
              for(var j in data[i]) {
                keys.push(j);
                if(data[i][j] === '') {
                  this.isFormValid = false;
                  return;
                } else {
                  this.isFormValid = true;
                }
              }
            }
          }

          this.allMandatoryFieldsExists = this.mandatoryField.every(x => keys.indexOf(x) >= 0);
        }

        if(this.jsonform.dirty && (!this.isFormValid || !this.allMandatoryFieldsExists)){
            console.log("form is dirty and not valid")
            // this.alertService.error("Json not correct. Please fix!");
        }else{
            console.log("form is dirty but valid")
        }
      });
```