# To highlight the selected row in mat-selection list and show its corresponding data by default

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

When we hover over the first column of the table a tooltip appears and then on clikcing on the button presnt in the tooltip mat dialog opens up.

The data loads but for the first time when the dialog opens up the row is not selected by default.

**Note:** (after the dialog has opened then on selecting any row its corresponding data loads and the row gets higlighted ,so this part works, but default highlighting of the left section row does not work when the popup opens for the first time)

The dialog contains 2 sections left and Edit json and. In the left whichever row is selected its corresponding data on the right side as json is shown.

alert-dialog.component.html

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column">
        <span class="sub-section p-t-26 p-b-10">Predefined Alerts</span>
        <div class="alert-select">
            <mat-selection-list #preDefAlertList (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event)">
                <mat-list-option #option *ngFor="let preDef of data.data; let i = index" [value]="i" [ngClass]="option.selected ? 'selected-option' : ''">
                  {{preDef.alert}}
                </mat-list-option>
            </mat-selection-list>
        </div>
        <span class="sub-section p-t-10 p-b-10">Custom Alerts</span>
        <div class="alert-select">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

alert-dialog.component.ts

```
export class AlertDialogComponent {

@ViewChild(MatSelectionList) preDefAlertList: MatSelectionList;
jsonform: FormGroup;

constructor( public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AlertDialogComponent>,
             @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData, private alertService: AlertService,
             private fb: FormBuilder) {
        console.log(data);
        this.jsonform = this.fb.group({
            json: [data['data'][0].conditionals]
          });      
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.jsonform.statusChanges.subscribe(() => {
        if(!this.jsonform.valid && this.jsonform.dirty){
            console.log("form is dirty and not valid")
        }else{
            console.log("form is dirty but valid")
        }
      });

    this.preDefAlertList.selectionChange.subscribe((s: MatSelectionListChange) => {
        this.preDefAlertList.deselectAll();
        s.option.selected = true;
    });
}

selectionChanged(event: MatSelectionListChange) {
    this.jsonform.setValue({
      json: this.data['data'][event.option.value].conditionals
    });
  }

onAddNewAlert(){
    if(!this.jsonform.valid && this.jsonform.dirty){
        console.log("final validation")
    }
 }
}
```

stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-uwsbqa?file=app/alert-dialog/alert-dialog.component.html

***This below link is the older version before I did the changes where data was loading in mat dialog and the row was getting highlighted***

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-qxxgcp?file=app%2Falert-dialog%2Falert-dialog.component.html

Comment: What's `option` in `[ngClass]="option.selected ? 'selected-option' : ''"`? A property called `option` isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: As I mentioned to you before, you should really recreate your problem using a minimal example. You have posted so much code that it's hard to know what your specific problem is. I doubt many people are going to be willing to work out what the desired functionality is, and then debug your huge component. Your questions generally generate answers that are guessing at the problem, with you replying that their guess doesn't work. This is just a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I quickly can propose to you is to add ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook and here mark the first option as selected.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.preDefAlertList.options.first.selected = true;
  }
```

EDIT - according to your comment

Please look at this example. Now I preselect element which was clicked and display its details on the right side.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-ki4r2q?file=app/alert-dialog/alert-dialog.component.ts

Comment: thanks, but not hardcoded, depending on which ever row the tooltip button was clicked that particular row should be highlighted in the dialog popup under Left section by default when the dialog popup opens up.

Answer (score 0):

try to use (selected) as input in mat-selection-list tag and then pass the parameter in the selectionChange Methode

Answer (score 0):

If you want "mark as selected" a row, you can has a variable

```
   selected:number=-1;
```

when you defined the mat-row, you add let i=index and you can change the style.background if i==selected, e.g.

```
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let i=index columns: displayedColumns;" [style.background-color]="i==selected?'red':null"></tr>
```

The last step if give value to the variable selected. For this, in a td, you can pass the row (futhermore the element)

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=index" 
     (click)="selected=i"> 
     {{element.position}} 
</td>
```

in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yinaw9?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html) if you "click" on "position", you see the row "selected".

In your case just in button you can add `selected=i`

```
  <button (click)="selected=i;
     onClick($event,(this.paginator.pageIndex == 0 ?  i : 
       i + this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize))">
     Click
  </button>
```

Don't forget if you want "des-select" equal the variable to -1

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  this.selected=-1;
});
```

Comment: I was looking for <mat-list-option> as selected row by default when the dialog popup opens up under Left section :) , sorry if I was not able to explain it(After the dialog opens by default none of the rows is selected , however when I click on any of the rows in dialog popup then the row gets selected but not by default when the dialog popup opens up, so I was trying to make it selected by default as well)

Comment: <mat-selection-list #preDefAlertList (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event)">
                <mat-list-option #option *ngFor="let preDef of data.data; let i = index" [value]="i" [ngClass]="option.selected ? 'selected-option' : ''">
                  {{preDef.alert}}
                </mat-list-option>
            </mat-selection-list> ,  this row to be selected by default when the popup opens up